# How to use LDAP in Lift Framework

Tags: scala, lift, scala-maven-plugin

Does anyone have a good example showing how to incorporate LDAP to a Lift Scala Project? I have problems adding the dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
      <artifactId>lift-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the project tag throws me an error saying it couldnt find the version in [1.4.5-rc1,1.4.5] to match range [1.4,1.4.3) javax.mail:mail:jar:null

Any ideas?? Thank u